# What would you call a person that nags a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests

If say one party has agreed to paint a shed and is now getting nagged by the nagger to do it. Is there a term better than "nagger"?

Comment: I'd call such a person a _tenacious pest_, a _broken record_, or a _pit-bull nag_.

Comment: It's certainly understandable why you're looking for an alternative term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_Apologies_to_Jesse_Jackson

Comment: @TheEnglishChicken LOL. That's certainly something to keep in mind.

Comment: One who nags is a "nag".

Comment: If it's a woman who is "overbearing", you could call her a **termagant**.      http://www.google.com/search?q=termagant&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en

Answer (score 4):

[Fishwife](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fishwife) could be relevant if the context is right...

> A woman regarded as coarse and **shrewishly abusive**

Or just a nag (rather than a nagger.)

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, many terms for "one who nags" (including *fishwife* and *scold*, nominated above) apply solely or primarily to a woman—a phenomenon that I can't say does our language proud. Other terms of this type include *hen* (whence *hen-pecked*), *shrew*, *termagant*, *harridan*, *harpy*, and (a Yiddish term) *klippeh*. Given their sex bias, I would advise against using any of them.

Fortunately, Yiddish also offers three excellent and more-or-less gender-neutral terms: *kvetcher*, *nudnik*, and *noodge*, the last of which I use regularly. If you're limited to plain English, I second the previous suggestions of *nag* and *pest*.

Answer (score 3):

Noun *[scold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scold#Noun)* (“A person fond of abusive language, in particular a troublesome and angry woman”) also is relevant.  (Note, wiktionary tags it as obsolete.)

Answer (score 3):

***"needler", "nettler", "harrasser"***, and my favorite, ***"haranguer"*** (from harangue) in this context:

verb [with object]
 lecture (someone) at length in an aggressive and critical manner, "he harangued the public on their ignorance"

Answer (score 3):

The bare stem "nag" can be used on its own to refer to someone who nags: "You're such a nag!"

[Merriam Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nag) gives it as their third definition of the word:

> one who nags habitually

"Nag" as a noun can also refer to an old or unhealthy/low-quality horse, but it is unlikely the two usages would be confused in context.